# apply function to all meaningful combination in a list and save in matrix format

Tags: r, function, matrix, lapply

I want to apply a function (distance between distance matrices) to a list of distance matrices and extract the calculated value in a matrix/table format.

Using `ecodist`package for the calculation and nested `lapply` to make all possible combination of the `MRM`distance calculation.

Part 1:

```
library("ecodist")

#example data
data(graze) 

#make list to get it looking like my data
grazelist<-as.list.data.frame(graze) 
    
#all vs all distance combination
grazedist<-lapply(names (grazelist),function(z) 
               lapply(names(grazelist),function(f)
              MRM(dist(grazelist [[z]])~ dist(grazelist[[f]]),nperm=1)))
```

This makes all vs. all possible combinations, but I only need all combination in one way (half the matrix), as calculation takes very long and the result for the second half is the same. Any idea how to solve this?

## Part 2:

I would like to gather only the `dist` value under `$coef`per calculation in a matrix format for follow up processing. In this case `1.000000e+00`.

R output looks like this:

```
> head(grazedist[[1]])
[[1]]
[[1]]$`coef`
                     dist(grazelist[[z]]) pval
Int                          8.881784e-16    1
dist(grazelist[[f]])         1.000000e+00    1

[[1]]$r.squared
  R2 pval 
   1    1 

[[1]]$F.test
           F       F.pval 
3.753766e+18 1.000000e+00
```

I know how to get it as `txt` or `csv` file for a simple R output not processed from a list (and called `MRM_calculation`).

```
write.table(MRM_calculation$coef[2,1],file="file.txt")
```

But how can I collect all `dist` values of `$coef` in a data frame, table or directly matrix format from a list?

something like:

```
mapply(write.csv2, x=grazedist$coef, 
file=paste(names(grazedist),"value.csv"))
```

I´m using larger matrices (1500x1500) in a list, but hope the example data `graze` are sufficient as a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `combn` which generates for your example data only 351 combinations rather than 729 combination (27 X 27) using nested `lapply`. You can then apply the function to every combination using the `FUN` argument in `combn` and extract the `dist` value in `coef` and write it to a dataframe.

```
library(ecodist)
df <- data.frame(value = combn(names(grazelist), 2, function(x)
         MRM(dist(grazelist[[x[1]]])~ dist(grazelist[[x[2]]]),nperm=1)$coef[[2]]))
```

and then write this to csv

```
write.csv(df, "/path/to/file/filename.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: thanks for nice suggestion! Just for better understanding, what is the `,2,` doing between `combn(names(grazelist), 2, function(x)` ?

Comment: @KonradWeber 2 specifies number of elements to choose from vector `names(grazelist)`. So in this example, it creates combination of 2 names. See for example output of `combn(c("ab", "cd", "ef"), 2)`. You can also read more about it at `?combn`.